# Templates for Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, multisite, permalinks, templates

I am working on a **custom theme** for **a network of sites** that are deployed under a **WordPress MultiSite installation**.

Within these theme I create 4 **custom post types** that have two taxonomies added to all of them. The first taxonomy is the `post_tag` one and the other is a a custom taxonomy that resembles the `category` one.

I've chosen that all of my 4 **custom post types** to have their *own taxonomy category* because I did not want any category **bleed** within the post types.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function o_post_types()
{
    $post_types = array(
        'articole' => array(
            'name' => 'Articole',
            'single' => 'Articol',
            'icon' => 'dashicons-admin-post'
        ),
        'evenimente' => array(
            'name' => 'Evenimente',
            'single' => 'Eveniment',
            'icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt'
        ),
        'concursuri' => array(
            'name' => 'Concursuri',
            'single' => 'Concurs',
            'icon' => 'dashicons-awards'
        ),
        'fotografii' => array(
            'name' => 'Fotografii',
            'single' => 'Fotografie',
            'icon' => 'dashicons-format-image'
        ),
        'promotii' => array(
            'name' => 'Promoții',
            'single' => 'Promoție',
            'icon' => 'dashicons-share'
        )
    );

    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        $icon = $post_type['icon'];
        $name_lower = strtolower($post_type['name']);
        $single_lower = strtolower($post_type['single']);
        if ($post_type['name'] == 'Promoții') {
            $name_lower = 'promotii';
            $single_lower = 'promotie';
        }
        $labels = array(
            'name' => $post_type['name'],
            'singular_name' => $post_type['single'],
            'add_new' => 'Adaugă ' . $single_lower,
            'add_new_item' => 'Adaugă ' . $single_lower . ' nou',
            'edit_item' => 'Editează ' . $single_lower,
            'new_item' => $post_type['single'] . ' nou',
            'all_items' => 'Listă ' . $name_lower,
            'view_item' => 'Afișează ' . $single_lower,
            'search_items' => 'Caută în ' . $name_lower,
            'not_found' => 'Nici un ' . $single_lower . ' găsit.',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nici un ' . $single_lower . ' găsit în Gunoi.',
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => $post_type['name']
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => $name_lower, 'with_front' => false),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments'),
            'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
            'menu_icon' => $icon
        );
        register_post_type("cpt_" . $single_lower, $args);

        $labels = array(
            'name' => 'Categorii',
            'singular_name' => 'Categorie',
            'search_items' => 'Caută Categorii',
            'all_items' => 'Toate Categoriile',
            'parent_item' => 'Categorie Părinte',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Categorie Părinte:',
            'edit_item' => 'Modifică Categorie',
            'update_item' => 'Actualizează Categorie',
            'add_new_item' => 'Adaugă Categorie nouă',
            'new_item_name' => 'Numele noii categorii',
            'menu_name' => 'Categorii',
        );
        $args = array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'slug' => $name_lower,
                'with_front' => false
            ),
        );
        register_taxonomy("tax_" . $name_lower, "cpt_" . $single_lower, $args);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1***

The file names are as follow:

- `taxonomy-articole.php`
- `taxonomy-concursuri.php`
- `taxonomy-evenimente.php`
- `taxonomy-fotografii.php`
- `taxonomy-promotii.php`

I am trying to display a list as a **category view** of all `cpt`s that have that term. Ex: a `cpt_evenimente` (or `cpt_events` in English) will have a `tax_evenimente` **term** (or `tax_events` in English) like so:

*Skate-park skateboard showoff* `cpt` will have assigned a *Outdoor Event* `term` and it will have to be displayed because of its term in the `taxonomy-evenimente.php` loop.

The problem is that the templates for each taxonomy does not load. What is there to be done?

Comment: what are your taxonomy template filenames? are you trying to load a taxonomy term archive?

Comment: Do not use hyphens in your names, make use of underscores to separate words

Comment: @Milo I have edited my question. I am trying to display all `cpt`s that belong to all terms found within a certain taxonomy for now.

Comment: @PieterGoosen: No more hyphens, only underscores. Same problem.

Comment: if the taxonomy is `tax_evenimente`, the template should be `taxonomy-tax_evenimente.php`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have totally missed the naming convention when coming to the [taxonomy archive pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display), and most probably the same goes for your [archive pages for your custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Type_Archive_display)

Here is how your taxonomy archive pages should look like

- **taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php** - If the taxonomy were `sometax`, and taxonomy's term were `someterm` WordPress would look for `taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php`. In the case of Post Formats, the taxonomy is `post_format` and the terms are `post_format-{format}`. i.e. `taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php`
- **taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php** - If the taxonomy were `sometax`, WordPress would look for `taxonomy-sometax.php`
- **taxonomy.php**
- **archive.php**
- **index.php**

So, all your taxonomy templates should be called `taxonomy-tax_{$name_lower}.php` where `$name_lower` is the name assigned to the variable.

Another issue that I brought up in my comments to your posts was

> Do not use hyphens in your names, make use of underscores to separate words

This is now the opportunity to test your names with and without hyphens and see how that affect how your templates are used.

Example:

If you make your taxonomy name `tax-mytax` and you create a template `taxonomy-tax-mytax.php`, you will notice that this will not work, as wordpress reads your template as follow: `tax` is your taxonomy name and `mytax` is a term

One last thing, and I don't know if you intentionally left that out, but your function should be hooked to the `init` hook

**EDIT 1**

Just also another point on good practice, write your arguments in English and make them translatable. Someone that speaks a language different from yours will have a tough time figuring out what the labels mean, as would be the case with me :-). This is also the one big reason why your function should be hooked to `init` as to make the translators available

**EDIT 2**

It seems that your rewrite rules is causing your issue. From what was discussed in chat,

> I have a taxonomy named `tax_evenimente`. It is a category-like taxonomy. I have a term `Alte Evenimente` with the slug `alte-evenimente`. `site.com/evenimente/alte-evenimente` should be displayed with `taxonomy.php`.

Yes, that is what should happen with your rewrite rule, but it keeps on `404`ing.

<---SECTION SCRAPPED--->

**EDIT 3**

I have found a great plugin to help with the rewrite rules for your custom post types. It is called [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) (*NOTE: I have no affiliation to the plugin*). As your code currently stands, leave it in place

## Here is how everything works:

(*For the sake of examples, I'm going to use `cpt_evenimente` and `tax_evenimente`*)

- Download and install the [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)
- Go to your permalinks settings page and scroll down to the settings for your custom post types. This is how it will look

[image]

- Change `/%postname%/` to `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/` to get your desired URL
- Save your permalinks

Now, for the tests

- `site.com/evenimente/alte-evenimente/` Displays taxonomy archive for terms from taxonomy `tax_evenimente` on `taxonomy-tax_evenimente.php`
- `site.com/evenimente/` Displays the custom post type archive for custom post type `cpt_evenimente`
- `site.com/evenimente/2014/10/testing-posts-1/` Displays the single post `testing post 1`

Just a note, the checkbox for "Use custom permalink of custom taxonomy archive" should be unchecked

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17870/discussion-between-aifrim-and-pieter-goosen).

Comment: Please see my update. Your taxonomy pages should now work

Comment: I have made a test and it still gives conflict. I need to create a specific permastruct rewrite rule. I will do some further tests on this conflict and hopefully write a wiki about it.

Comment: On my side if I enter `site.com/evenimente/alte-evenimente` it works and `taxonomy-tax_evenimente.php` is used. Don't know if this will help

Comment: Did you have a `cpt` with the same `slug`?

Comment: I found this plugin yesterday as well but did not have time to test it. It works with it. Thank you for your time and stubbornness =D.

Comment: LOL, no problem. It was a nice challange for me. Glad all your problems is solved. Enjoy and good luck with your project. :-)