# Rewriting base name Taxonomy same Post Type

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have a Custom post type called "events" and taxonomy called "cat-events".
I'd like this structure:

1. **website.com/events/**
2. **website.com/events/post-name** (es: website.com/events/the-best-musical-2014)
3. **website.com/events/term-taxonomy/** (es: website.com/events/musical/)

How can I?

Comment: Check my last section of my [answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165256/31545)

Comment: @PieterGoosen I installed the plugin. It changes the custom post URL (website.com/events/post-name) and the URL term (website.com/events/taxonomy-name/term-name). But I'd like website.com/events/musical not website.com/events/cat-events/musical

I don't want to see the base name of taxonomy, but only the term (website.com/post-type/term/)