# template structure for CPT not clear

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

I am a little confused with CPT and custom taxonomies. I created CPT named 'Profiles' and did not create any custom taxonomies for it. So categories is the default taxonomy for it, I tried template, 'taxonomy-php.php' (ie my category in CPT) , but it displayed nothing. Dont know whats the issue, I also tried 'category-php.php' but it also didnt work. The code is correct i worked it for normal loop and it ran smoothly, please suggest me the right structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was using wrong structure, after looking through a bit more i found out exact difference for CPT and cutom taxonomies.
For custom post types the template structure is like:-\

```
single-{post-type}.php
archive-{post-type}.php
search.php
index.php
```

And for Custom taxonomies, the template structure I found out from here:-

Link:-[Templates for Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157862/templates-for-custom-post-types-and-custom-taxonomies)