# Taxonomy template page not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, archive-template

I have a taxonomy register with name doctor-services and I have a taxonomy template with name taxonomy-doctor-services.php but when I click on taxonomy link it does not display detail of the taxonomy.
Here is a code

```
  function doctors_custom_post(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Doctors',
        'singular_name' => 'Doctor',
        'add_new' => 'Add Doctor',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Doctor',
        'all_items' => 'All Doctors',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Item',
        'search_items' => 'Search Doctors',
        'not_found' => 'No record found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item'
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
            //'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tags'),
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'exclude_from_search' => false
            );
            register_post_type('my-doctor', $args);     
}
add_action('init', 'doctors_custom_post');
add_action( 'init', 'doctors_my_taxonomy');
function doctors_my_taxonomy(){
// custom post type taxonomies
        $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Doctor Departments',
        'singular_name' => 'Doctor Department',
        'add_new' => 'Add Department',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Department',
        'all_items' => 'All Departments',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Item',
        'update_item' => 'Update Department',
        'search_items' => 'Search Departments',
        'not_found' => 'No record found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item',
        'menu_name' => 'Departments'
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'doctor_departments'),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            );
            register_taxonomy('doctor-department', array('my-doctor'), $args);
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Diseases',
        'singular_name' => 'Diseases',
        'add_new' => 'Add Disease',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Disease',
        'all_items' => 'All Disease',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Item',
        'update_item' => 'Update Disease',
        'search_items' => 'Search Disease',
        'not_found' => 'No record found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item',
        'menu_name' => 'Diseases'
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'doctor_diseases'),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            );
            register_taxonomy('doctor-diseases', array('my-doctor'), $args);
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Services',
        'singular_name' => 'Service',
        'add_new' => 'Add Service',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Service',
        'all_items' => 'All Services',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Item',
        'update_item' => 'Update Service',
        'search_items' => 'Search Service',
        'not_found' => 'No record found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item',
        'menu_name' => 'Services'
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'doctor_services'),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            );
            register_taxonomy('doctor-services', array('my-doctor'), $args);
}
```

and taxonomy Services page

```
      <?php
      get_header(); ?>
      <div id="primary">
      <div id="content" class="content">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
       <h2> <?php 
        single_cat_title();
        ?>
        </h2>
        <?php category_description(); ?>
       </div>
        </div>
        </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and taxonomy link when I clicked

http://example.com/doctor_services/xray/

Please help where is the error

Comment: `Goto > settings >permalinks->select (post name) > save changes` this will refresh your permalinks structure.

Comment: I have already selected permalink post name

Comment: then just go to `permalinks` dont change anything just `save changes`

Comment: Your template should be taxonomy-doctor_services.php, else WP will look for services term under Doctor taxonomy. Check here https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png

Comment: I have saved permalinks after selecting a post name but problem not solved

Comment: I have also changed taxonomy to doctor_services and taxonomy page taxonomy-doctor_services.php but on front end side it does not display detail of that taxonomy.

Comment: try opening permalink settings once

Comment: Here is a reference link : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157862/templates-for-custom-post-types-and-custom-taxonomies#answer-165256

Comment: @Oliveradams naming it taxonomy-doctor-services.php wont work

Comment: I updated my answer @piyush

Comment: Now, I have changed the taxonomy name doctor_services and taxonomy page taxonomy-doctor_services.php and When I click the taxonomy link it redirects to home page.

Comment: @HeroWeb512 edit the code in your question so that we can see for any error

Comment: my two other taxonomies of this custom post type working fine but I am surprised about it why its not working fine.

Comment: did you try this@HeroWeb512, copy `archive.php` file and rename it to `archive-doctor-services.php` and `save changes` `permalinks` and try again because your code is working fine on my localhost.

Comment: my two other taxonomies are doctor-department with taxonomy page taxonomy-doctor-department and doctor-disease with taxonomy page taxonomy-doctor-disease.php both are working fine

Comment: Yes @Oliver I have tried with archive-doctor-services.php but taxonomy link redirects to home page

Comment: Try to declare the taxanomy before the Custom post type. in some cases it works.

Comment: Its not going to its taxonomy template page taxonomy-doctor_services.php

Comment: @HeroWeb512 post your current register_taxonomy code

Comment: I have updated the code with all my registered taxonomy @Piyush

Comment: @HeroWeb512 the other two taxonomies work fine?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qtipu1&s=9#.WgrbuXqP-iU 
here is your working code example,

Comment: Yes @Piyush other taxonomies working fine but I dont know why its not working well

Comment: Yes I know @Oliver my coding is fine, I surprised myself

Comment: can u share the code you are using for `taxonomy-doctor_services.php` ?

Comment: Why not, let me to update my above code

Comment: I have updated the code @Oliver adams

Comment: Use `the_archive_title();` instead of `single_cat_title();` and `the_archive_description();` instead of `category_description();` and reply me if its work.

Comment: But title displays Service: Xray, it should display only Xray

Comment: i posted full working code in the answer section @HeroWeb512

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68747/discussion-between-oliver-adams-and-heroweb512).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `the_archive_title();` instead of `single_cat_title();` and `the_archive_description();` instead of `category_description();`

add this code to `functions.php`

```
add_filter('get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {
    return preg_replace('/^\w+: /', '', $title);
});
```